# How to create `Toolbar` with left, center, and right components in Swift for macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I'm writing a music app for macOS in SwiftUI, and hope its toolbar behave like this: Artwork with title at left, play controls at center, and inspector toggles at right, as shown below. However, it seems that they cannot be laid correctly at the same time.

[image]

So, I write a small demo to reproduce my problem here.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button("Left") { }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Button("Center") { }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button("Right") { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The right button is displayed at wrong placement. But if I delete left and center button, the right button will correctly appear at right of window as expected.

How can I fix this, and display components at left, center, and right at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `ToolbarItem` that contains only a `Spacer`

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
        Button("Left") { }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button("Center") { }
    }
    ToolbarItem {
        Spacer()
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button("Right") { }
    }
}
```